# Eclipse RCP-- how to do Pause/Resume button functionality with threads using(wait and notify)

Tags: eclipse, button, rcp, thread-synchronization

Problem statement:--

I have a UI button "**Perform**"-- which will initiate a big background process in loop in a different thread sequentially. 
As soon the process is started the button text will be toggled to "**Pause**"
Now on press of "Pause", I need to suspend the thread execution and "**Resume**" will finally notify to go ahead.

On button press"**Perform**",thread gets started, and button toggles to "**Pause**" and if I press Pause,thread is suspended.But I am not able to resume the running thread.If I check the Thread state in resume button press event, I get value=0 which is equivalent to NONe.  Please help. Following is my code....

> Blockquote

```
performBButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            Button btnToggle = (Button) e.getSource();
            MyJob myJob = new MyJob();
            if (btnToggle.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Perform")) {
                btnToggle.setText("Pause");
                myJob.schedule();

            }
            else if (btnToggle.getText().equals("Pause")) {
                buttonToggle.setText("Resume");
                isPaused=!isPaused;
            }
            else if (btnToggle.getText().equals("Resume")) {
                buttonToggle.setText("Pause");
                isPaused=!isPaused;
                synchronized (myJob) {
                    myJob.notify();
                  }
            }
        }
    });

class MYJob extends Job{
   public void run(IProgessMonito monitor) {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           for (int i=0;i<50000;i++) {
               System.out.println("Iteration "+i +isPaused);
                    synchronized (this) {
                        if (isPaused) {                               
                                wait();
                            } 
                        }
                    }
         Thread.sleep(1000);//I have removed try catch while pasting here

    }
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing wait() to myThread.wait() actually solved my problem, by declaring myThread globally. but its not the correct way , any further  suggestions will be helpful...